# Make Camera Bounds

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I'm new here and I have a question. (Help me Google Translate).
At first I make camera from this video.

[First video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aVZuL9ocrk&index=8&list=PLiyfvmtjWC_Up8XNvM3OSqgbJoMQgHkVz)

*First script (CameraController)*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerController player;

    [Header ("Привязка камеры")]
    public bool isFollowing;
    public float xOffset;
    public float yOffset;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();

        isFollowing = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (isFollowing)
            transform.position = new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x+xOffset, player.transform.position.y+yOffset, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

[Second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6xmOMsRWeo)

*Second script (CameraFollow)*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector2 velocity;

    public float smoothTimeY;
    public float smoothTimeX;

    //public GameObject player;
    public PlayerController player;

    public bool bounds;

    public Vector3 minCameraPos;
    public Vector3 maxCameraPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player");
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        float posX = Mathf.SmoothDamp (transform.position.x, player.transform.position.x, ref velocity.x, smoothTimeX);
        float posY = Mathf.SmoothDamp (transform.position.y, player.transform.position.y, ref velocity.x, smoothTimeY);

        transform.position = new Vector3 (posX, posY, transform.position.z);

        if (bounds)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minCameraPos.x, maxCameraPos.x),
                                             Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minCameraPos.y, maxCameraPos.y),
                                             Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, minCameraPos.z, maxCameraPos.z));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do like in second video, but when my hero died. He becomes invisible.
How to fix it?

[MyProject](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvdp50p6w6g5324/Lost%20Penguin%20v.0.0.8.1.rar?dl=0)

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

*Script(LevelManeger)*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelManeger : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject currentCheckpoint;

    private PlayerController player;

    public HealthManager healthManager;

    [Space(10)]
    [Header ("Штраф")]
    public int pointPenaltyOnDeath;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController> ();

        healthManager = FindObjectOfType<HealthManager> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void RespawnPlayer()
    {
        ScoreManager.AddPoints (-pointPenaltyOnDeath);
        Debug.Log ("Player Respawn");
        player.transform.position = currentCheckpoint.transform.position;
        healthManager.FullHealth ();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you in your playerscript when the player dies?

Comment: @Mattias Update.Also you can check my scripts in my project.Check link.

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: @HamzaHasan no/

Comment: I tried to run your project, but as usual all references are removed and some objects are even not in scene and your script is trying to access it

Comment: but in second scene everything seems fine, on player die you are respawning it. So what is the problem?

Comment: @HamzaHasan Sorry, wrong version of the game.Download the game again. I changed the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33228/discussion-between-artik-slayer-and-hamza-hasan).

Comment: Sorry, I was busy last night, check answer @ArtikSlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Z` position of `Checkpoint` gameObject from `-10` to `0`.

This is because your MainCamera has clipping planes with `0.3` to `1000` and you are spawning your `Hero` even behind the `Near Plane (Clipping plane)`.

**`Clipping Planes`** are the attributes of `Camera` to let `Camera` know that `From` where `To` where `Camera` has to render all stuff.